# How to link the content of two cells

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with 2 different sheets. In one i have a list of cities, in the other one i have all the trains that go in that specific city. I have linked the city's name cells with the corresponding in the list. If i add another city and reorganize the list in alphabetic order the trains sheet will have the city's names all changed. How can i connect the content of two different cells so that if i reorganize the list the names in the trains sheet will not change? I looked gor a solution in the official microsoft forum but i didn't find anything

Comment: check this please: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Use `XLOOKUP()` function.

Comment: So, also check out index() with match() as xlookup() is only in the newer Excel versions.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm using VLOOKUP() function and it works
2. In CITIES-STATIONS.xlsx file I'm taking 3 columns as array I'm
   getting the column 3 to show in Trains.xlsx file

I added Florida City and is taking the value of the station the formula is in the Trains.xlsx file:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'[1-CITIES-STATIONS.xlsx]Stations'!$A$1:$C$44,3,FALSE)

=VLOOKUP(Searching Value, Array ,Column to get in to the Trains File, Bolean Value in case null)

1-CITIES-STATIONS.xls file
A            B       C     
City        State   Station Name
Alpine      TX      (ALP)
Alton       IL      (ALN)
Arkadelphia AR      (ARK)
Austin      TX      (AUS)
Benson      AZ      (BEN)
Bloomington IL      Uptown Station (BNL)
Carlinville IL      (CRV)
Chicago     IL      Union Station (CHI)
Cleburne    TX      (CBR)
Dallas      TX      Union Station (DAL)
Del Rio     TX      (DRT)
Deming      NM      (DEM)
El Paso     TX      Union Depot (ELP)
Florida     MI      Amtrak Florida <------
Fort Worth  TX      (FTW)
Hope        AR      (HOP)



2-TRAINS.xls file
    A                         B                  C
Train Company               City               Station
Amtrak.                     Malvern             (MVN)   <---formula here
Amtrak.                     Arkadelphia         (ARK)
Amtrak.                     Palm Springs        Amtrak Station (PSN)
Amtrak.                     Florida             Amtrak Florida  <------
Norfolk Southern Railway.   Hope                (HOP)
Norfolk Southern Railway.   Texarkana           (TXA)
Norfolk Southern Railway.   Marshall            (MHL)
Norfolk Southern Railway.   Longview            (LVW)
Norfolk Southern Railway.   Mineola             (MIN)
Union Pacific Railroad.     Dallas  U.S.        (DAL)
Union Pacific Railroad.     Fort Worth          (FTW)
Union Pacific Railroad.     Cleburne            (CBR)
Union Pacific Railroad.     McGregor            (MCG)
Union Pacific Railroad.     Temple              (TPL)
Union Pacific Railroad.     Taylor              (TAY)
BNSF Railway.               Austin              (AUS)
```

Good luck!